# Natsort inside of loop

Tags: php, sorting, natsort

*Please see the comments. I realized that the question(s) I should be asking are in another place altogether in my case, perhaps that'll be useful to you.*

I am trying to optimize my cod a bit and at first, I am generating an array of strings: `[String1, String3, String2]` from an object. Problem is, I do it like this:

```
$collection = [...];

$strings = array_map(
    function( $item ) {
        return $item->getName();
    },
    $collection
);

natsort( $strings )
```

Is there no way to do the sorting as I loop using `array_map`? This is hogging performance when combined with other things.

Comment: Kind of impossible to sort things before they exist , and unless the array is enormous it shouldn't have any noticeable performance impact.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, but here we deal with sorting items as they are added, not after. The array we're talking about can have upwards of ~1000 items, on its own, it's not a hog. Combine it with the basics of any web app and you can see it adds up.

Comment: You can not sort while doing array_map. You would have to loop over the data yourself, and then either sort the result after each new item that was added, or implement your own logic to _insert_ elements at the correct position into the result.

Comment: What is the _actual_ “hogger” here to begin with - the mapping of the data, or the sorting? Probably the latter. The comparison for a natural sort is way more complex, than a simple alphabetical one.

Comment: @misorude Naturally. Of course I was looking to re-write this entirely if it was called for. Unfortunately, I can't see how `natsort` works in C-land so that I can copy it to my own needs.

Comment: @misorude It's the sorting.

Comment: _“Unfortunately, I can't see how natsort works in C-land so that I can copy it to my own needs”_ - the natural language comparison for two string values already exists in PHP - `strnatcmp`/`strnatcasecmp`. Implementing _that_ yourself as well, is likely not going to be any faster, I suppose.

Comment: And http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/ has a pretty good explanation of the comparison rules, and implementations in C as well, if you still want to look into that part specifically any deeper.

Comment: @misorude Certainly. I just wanna explore my options for now. I saw the comment with `uksort` from `natsort`, I'll write some tests to see if the output is still the same using `uksort( $strings, 'strnatcasecmp')`

Comment: `uksort` would sort an array by its keys, you’d want `usort` here in this case.

Comment: @misorude At the same time, I'm not looking specifically for `natsort`. I just wanna use sorting so that "insertion order" doesn't matter but I think that's another question.

Comment: @DanielM So, basically you are combining arrays and doing an array_map on them and in the end sorting them. Am I right?

Comment: Then I would check what you get with a standard alphabetical sort first, maybe that is quicker already. (That just needs to go character-by-character, and doesn’t have to apply any additional rules/logic.)

Comment: @DanielM Can you show a sample of input and output for more clarity?

Comment: @vivek_23 I will actually ask my question with my original intent given I realized that perhaps I was looking at this from the wrong perspective because I think what am trying to achieve given the current context is **wrong.**

Comment: @vivek_23 I've asked another question related to this (the original intent): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285987/computing-sum-of-strings-while-accounting-for-swapped-characters